# Address attributes of HTML tags by CSS selector

Tags: javascript, css, dom, selectors-api

I'm loading the name and id attributes of a `<form>` called contactForm to a javascript array like this:

```
const flds=[];
contactForm.querySelectorAll("input").
    forEach( value => { 
        flds.push([value.id, value.name])
    });
;
console.log(flds);
```

Can I do that directly without a loop? Something like:

```
const flds=contactForm.querySelectorAll("input [name,id]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can do is a map function.

```js
const flds = [...contactForm.querySelectorAll("input")].map(el => [el.id, el.name])
```